# Python não retorna arquivos dentro de um diretório

Tags: python

Boa noite sou novo em programação Python porém criei este código usando os.listdr e não retornou qualquer resultado dos arquivos dentro pasta.
Se alguém tiver alguma idéia de como resolver agradeço muito.
segue o código:

```
import os

def rename_files():

#(1) Obter nomes de arquivos de uma pasta
file_list = os.listdr(r"C:\Users\Deivid\Pictures\Imagens\prank")
print (file_list)
```

Comment: Em erros desse tipo, a primeira coisa é usar o principio [KISS,](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keep_It_Simple) tente rodar somente com a raiz do drive: `file_list = os.listdr(r"C:\")`

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda amigo, tentei rodar somente a raiz porém não obtive sucesso.

Comment: Qual foi a msg de erro?

Comment: Não havia mensagem de erro, o codigo compilava porém no shell não exibia o conteúdo do diretório, apenas o cursor ficava piscando.

Answer (score 1):

Galera obrigado pela ajuda, porém solucionei o problema e consegui rodar o script, abaixo segue o script reformulado:

```
import os
def rename_files():     
list_files = os.listdir(r"diretório")
print(list_files)
rename_files()
```

O problema é que estava faltando fechar a função em vazio
   **def rename_files():
   rename_files()**

Comment: E qual é a diferença desse código para o da pergunta? O que exatamente estava errado? Se este funcionou e não entendi porque o outro não, o problema não foi solucionado. Se entendeu, edite a resposta é descreva o erro.

Comment: Galera segue o retorno que faltava do problema.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo jeito é erro de sintaxe
rodei o script aqui e funcionou

```
def rename_files():
...     file_list = os.listdir(r"diretorio")
...     print(file_list)
```

Comment: Acredito que não amigo, pois o script é o mesmo..estou em dúvida se é algo relacionado a versão do Python.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo vc esqueceu um 'i':

```
import os

def rename_files():

    #(1) Obter nomes de arquivos de uma pasta
    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Goku\MaisdeOitoMil")
    print (file_list)

rename_files()
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda consertei o erro aqui porém ainda sem sucesso, o programa roda normal porém não aparece os arquivos do diretório.